# Group list of different enums by enum

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have this class that accepts a list of [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) errors and places them in a dictionary.

```
public class ErrorList<T> : ISerializable where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public IReadOnlyDictionary<T, string> Errors { get; private set; }

    public ErrorList(IList<ValidationFailure> errors)
    {
        Errors = (from e in errors
                  select new
                  {
                      e.PropertyName,
                      e.CustomState
                  }).ToDictionary(t => (T)t.CustomState, t => t.PropertyName);
    }
}
```

The constructor above works fine when the list contains values of one particular enum type (eg. `CustomerError`).

Now I need to expand the above so that the errors passed might contain different enum types (eg. `CustomerError`, `CustomerBankAccountError`, etc), so I was going to add a new property:

```
public IReadOnlyDictionary<Type, IReadOnlyDictionary<object, string>> ExtraErrors { get; private set; }
```

Using `Linq`, how is it possible to:

1. Filter out and place the enum values of type `T` in the "Errors" dictionary?
2. Filter out and group the remaining enum values into separate dictionaries within "ExtraErrors"?

Comment: So, `ValidationFailure.CustomState` is an `object` property which can contain different boxed enum values, and you would like to group them by enum type? Also, this class won't be a generic `ErrorList<T>` then anymore?

Comment: @Groo It will be partially generic!

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate that a bit. What will be generic in this class?

Comment: 99.9% of the time the second property "ExtraErrors" is always going to be null so the original generic functionality still stands. I need to expand this class to support additional enum types to avoid a slightly major rewrite of the app. Validation takes place server-side in a WebApi application, and this class is serialized to the client and the dictionaries bound to lists for displaying the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use LINQ, you can simply use `where` to filter elements into two collections:

```
public ErrorList(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> errors)
{
    // e.CustomState is of type T ?
    Errors = errors
        .Where(e => (e.CustomState is T))
        .ToDictionary(e => (T)e.CustomState, e => e.PropertyName);

    // e.CustomState is not of type T ?
    ExtraErrors = errors
        .Where(e => !(e.CustomState is T))
        .GroupBy(e => e.CustomState.GetType())
        .ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key,
            g => (IReadOnlyDictionary<object, string>)g.ToDictionary(
                      e => e.CustomState, 
                      e => e.PropertyName));
}
```